# virtualbox - virtualization is enabled but not working

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Ok, I have the most recent version of virtualbox installed, my computer (HP) has an AMD A10, 64bit Windows 10 OS and 6Gb RAM.

I created a virtual machine with Windows 7, there I wanted to create a new virtual machine (a VM2 in a VM1), but I cant run it because I have no virtualization enabled in the VM1.

[image: This image is the error I'm getting]

ok, so I checked the VM1 configuration and the virtualization is enabled in the virtualbox settings. I've tried with all the Paravirtualization interfaces and always having the Hardware Virtualization enabled (VT-x and AMD-V).
I really don't know why this is happening if this is all suposed to be enabled and there arent documentations of similar issues.

I tried changing the number of CPUs used by the VM1 and all the interfaces.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I seach for 2 days and nothing worked for me.. then i find the solution:

The problem is in Windows 10... u need to disable Hyper-V Manager ...

1) make sure in your BIOS cpu virtualization is enable.

2) open your CMD as administrator

3) in your desktop folder type `bcdedit` and look for hypervisorlaunchtype in the bottom ... if it is Auto or enable we need to disable it !!!!!!

[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3XFi.png)

4) type in your cmd  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

5) Restart your OS and be happy !!!

i know this is a old question ... but for everyone who have a similar problem i hope it helps !!

Comment: Thank you. I finally got the option to select 64-bit virtualbox systems

Comment: This makes virtual box work on AMD machines but breaks Android emulator if you are using that.

Comment: Thank's. this is the only solution that worked whatsoever on my laptop. google didn't helped me :( except to find this +1. It's an old answer, but still quite accurate.

Comment: @HiteshBisht May be it break on AMD as I didn't check it on AMD. But Android Emulator works perfectly on Intel even if you disable the `hypervisorlaunchtype` property.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried several solutions and restarts before this!

Comment: For some reason, my linux subsystem for windows stops working if I do this. It does let me use virutalbox and vmware though!

Comment: Thank, i was enable win10 sandbox. And other softwave say VT is not enable....

Comment: This solution did not even work for me! :(

Comment: You can reenable it using `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Answer (score 5):

Turn off the core isolation security provided in the Windows Defender Security Centre.
I found that enabling it turn off your Intel Virtualization technology feature while it is enabled in BIOS.
Steps to follow:
1. Go to Windows Defender Security Centre.
2. Search for Device Security in the left Panel and click on it.
3. Now click on core isolation.
4. Turn off the memory intergrity security.
If it didnt turn off and show (This is managed by your device Administrator) then follow the steps by searching on google.
You may need to download a file and enter into registry to turn it Off. Just google it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct, however there is something worth mentioning:
Usually the **Hyper-V Manager** is enabled by **Docker** (Docker runs on top of HV Manager), in my case it only worked after :

- Removing Docker
- dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

the command line will ask you to restart, then you will able to run VX images!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my os is windows 10, I enabled virtualization VTx and Vtd in BIOS, but it didn't work. After seaching online, I sovled this problem. Hope this can help people.

1. Press Windows key + X and select "Apps and Features".
2. Then click "Programs and Features" link.
3. Then click the "Turn Windows features on or off" link on the left pane.
4. Locate "Virtual Machine Plateform" option and check it.
5. (These two steps I'm not sure : Locate "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Plateform" option and unmark them.)
6. Click OK to save the changes and reboot.
   Below is the screenshot:
   [enable Virtualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXaxj.jpg)

And you can check if it is working fine in task manager, in the performance tab you can see whether the virtualization enabled or not.