# Virtualization enabled but is not working

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

The issue is that although I enabled virtualization everywhere, both wsl2 and Docker Desktop see it as disabled.

Details ->

Environment:

- Win 10 Pro, OS Build 19043
- x64 based system
- FUJITSU Lifebook E546
- motherboard FJNB291

Configuration:

- Hyper-V tried both enabled/disabled, checked in Turn Win features on/off
  -> I tried to enable/disable also via Cmd Prompt and PowerShell, this seems working well
- BIOS Virtualization Technology [enabled]
- BIOS Intel VT -d [tried both enabled/disabled]
- enabled virtualization based security -> I could not disable it anyways, so it is enabled.

Comment: Not understandably closed. Or, at least, StackOverflow is not consistent with that since there are many existing tickets like this one, just with a different technology stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Disabling the **Hyper V Manager**

Follow the steps:

1.*Open CMD As Admin*

2.*Type In* `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and click *enter*.

Then You Have to restart Ur PC... Hope This Works!

**Reference**: [virtualbox - virtualization is enabled but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552810/virtualbox-virtualization-is-enabled-but-not-working)

Comment: It unfortunately did not help.

Comment: actually:
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
did the job. So thanks for the hint.